# How do I catch the exception in windows application in c#?

Tags: .net, exception

1. Where should we catch exception

   - In Layer Boundary (UI->BLL & BLL->DAL)
   - In that methods where there is no interaction between Layers only some business logic present
2. How do I write exception in Save/Delete where some DML statement executing?

   - What should I write in DAL end?
   - What should I write in BLL end?
   - What should I write in UI end?
3. In Get/Load method How do we handle exception

   - What should I write in BLL end?
   - What should I write in UI end?
4. Should I catch System exception?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific technology or language or is this a general question?

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 framework and C# language

Answer (score 2):

The general rule with exception handling is: only handle exceptions your layer will be able to deal with.  If you can't, let the higher ones handle it.